# Leaflet .addLayer() fails in function, works at the console

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, leaflet

I think this means I'm missing something basic about the working of nested functions in javascript, but I'm failing to add or remove a layer from a leaflet map [using a click function](https://github.com/GeoSprocket/sactree-map/blob/master/layers.js#L42-L53). Specifically, I have a leaflet map with numerous vector layers defined. One of these layers is added to the map [on page load](https://github.com/GeoSprocket/sactree-map/blob/master/layers.js#L128), and then subsequent layers are supposed to load on a click event in a layer selector.

Here's the function that handles the click, then updates the sidebar legend, updates classes in the layer selector, and **is supposed to** update the visible layer:

```
// ADD THE LAYER CONTROL FUNCTION
$('.layer').click(function() {
  var oldLayer = $('.active').attr('id');
  var newLayer = $(this).attr('id');
  console.log(oldLayer + ' --> ' + newLayer);
  $('#infobits').html('<h2>' + this.text + '</h2><hr>' + legendFormatter(
    this.id));
  map.removeLayer(oldLayer);
  $('.layer').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
  map.addLayer(newLayer);
});
```

Every time I click on a new layer I get `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`, no matter where I put the function (I even had it inside the .getJSON() call for a bit). What's perplexing is that is I go to the JS console in my browser and type **verbatim** what the function is producing on line 49 of the above script (`map.removeLayer(Percent_TC_bg)`), the map removes the layer in question.

What can I do to get my map adding and removing layers without error?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function means that the moment that line is being executed in code, map is undefined/null. Debug and check.

Comment: `map` is completely available inside the function. Logging `console.log(map.getCenter());` one line prior to `map.removeLayer(oldLayer)` produces the expected coordinates. Totally stumped.

Comment: Is the map live somewhere?

Comment: I just put it up [here](http://geosprocket.github.io/sactree-map).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suppose `TypeError` is thrown inside `addLayer` or `removeLayer`. [`Map#addLayer`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-addlayer) and [`#removeLayer`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-removelayer) accepts `ILayer` object as parameter, but `oldLayer` and `newLayer` is obviously `String`, which came directly from HTML element's ID property.

So changing `oldLayer` and `newLayer` to appreciate `ILayer` object will fix the problem, I guess.

Comment: This is going to sound horribly naive, but how would I cast a variable as an `ILayer` instead of a string?

Comment: You should keep ILayers in a dictionary and fetch them by the ID. Then use that object in addLayer/removeLayer calls.

Answer (score 2):

Edit: Igor beat me to it.

Mics is right - the HTML element's ID is a string, and doesn't reference the layer. You could do something like this after you define your layers to work around this issue:

```
var myLayers = {
    "Percent_TC_bg": Percent_TC_bg,
    "Percent_TC": Percent_TC
};
```

And then add the handler like so

```
$('.layer').click(function() {
  var oldLayer = myLayers[$('.active').attr('id')];
  var newLayer = myLayers[$(this).attr('id')];
  // ...
});
```

Comment: Wow, I can't shake the feeling that this is hacky and frowned upon, but I refuse to argue with the fact that it now works like a charm. Thanks so much!

Comment: You could ````eval()```` the id of the div, but that would be more frowned upon. When storing the names of JS variables as ids of DOM elements, it's fairly common practice to store references in an object.